# Portable Java on a Usb

Tags: java, ide, usb

How can I edit and run Java programs from a USB. I want to write Java programs and compile them in a USB without needing administrator permission. The programs are not going to be that big just a couple of classes it's more for practice/testing. The only thing I could find was DrJava which is a light weight development environment but i'm not sure if that would do the the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2).

Since Eclipse is self-contained (doesn't require installation on the host machine), you can just start it up and go. It's also pretty lightweight considering you're probably using at least an 8GB flash drive.

Also, you could just use Eclipse to create a new workspace on the flash drive by going to

```
File > Switch Workspace > Other...
```

Then just set it to a folder on your flash drive. Then you can just open the workspace when Eclipse starts up on whatever machine you're using.

Comment: don't you need to install the Java environment in the host machine also?

Comment: @franz1 That's a good point. One could also put a JRE installer on the flash drive.